# Comments on user profile not working

Tags: 8, comments

I want to add comments to user profiles. I added the comments in user profile under *Configuration > People > Account settings*, but when I add the field, the option to select the comment type is showing empty. What is the correct way to allow other users to give comments on user profiles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each **Comment Type** can only be applied to one type of entity (nodes (*content*), users, and taxonomy terms are examples of different types of entities).

By default, Drupal core only provides a comment type for nodes.

So, to add comments on users, you will need to create a user comment type.

1. Go to `/admin/structure/comment`.
2. Select *Add comment type*.
3. Add a **Label** such as *User comments*.
4. For **Target entity type**, select *Users*.
5. For the comments field at `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields`, select your new user comment type.